# Cannot dismiss flash messages in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

I'm generating success and alert flash notices when a user can login or has failed to login. I have followed the documentation, but for some reason when I click on the 'X', it will not close the error message.  Has anybody run into this problem? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

in my application this is found at `alpha-blog-se/app/views/layouts/_messages.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= msg %>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I think something is conflicting with this code elsewhere in my application. here's my git repo https://github.com/sorenessen/alpha-blog-se/tree/master. I'm moving from testing to development in my current capacity and this one has me stumped.

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: One alert: you shouldn't put the bootstrap file inside pack folder and import it again in application.js. It is being compiled twice. The best would be to add bootstrap with yarn and only import the CSS and JS at application.js: https://railsbytes.com/public/templates/x9Qsqx

Comment: Or at least move it to a 'src' folder, inside app/javascrip but out of 'packs'.

Comment: So should I just remove the whole JS folder from /packs and then run `rails app:template LOCATION='https://railsbytes.com/script/x9Qsqx'` in my terminal?

Comment: and thank you, @PedroSchmitt for your quick reply :)

Comment: Yes, you can do this, or make the configuration by hand looking at the script. But it will only import The Bootstrap in the right way, I don't know if will solve the close button problem (But as this appears to be a javascript problem, maybe it will solve)